# Jquery: how to get mutual parent div from array of divs (for equal height)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

Current scenario:
I have a page that is divided into columns. 
There are different blocks on my page that have the ".equalHeight" class assigned to them: 2 of them in first column, 1 in the middle and 2 in the third column.

When I select all blocks using the $(".equalHeight") selector, I get an array of elements.

How can I find the mutual parent for the ones in the first column, the second and the last column? 
I need the height from the first column, the second column and the third column, to assign the the children.

Is there an efficient way to do this using jquery? 
Also keep in mind that once the first and second element of the array are found, you won't need to do the check for the second one in the array, because it's already updated by the first one, thus making the loop faster...

Any ideas?

Thanks

M.

Comment: Could you give us some code to help and tell us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're going to iterate over the row checking `.outerHeight` and determine the biggest one. [Link to jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/)

**jquery-match-height** does a great job of this with jquery ([github page](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height)). It does a lot more than it sounds you need (both features-wise and in terms of browser compatability), but check out jquery.matchHeight.js's `lines 221-284`